# Java reflection unable to change structure

Tags: java, reflection

I'm enriching my knowledge about Java programming and I'm currently interested in reflection. I found this website http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/java-reflection-tutorial/

Here the write mentions the following:

> In Java, reflection is more about introspection, because you can not change structure of an object. There are some APIs to change accessibilities of methods and fields, but not structures.

I actually do not understand what he means with the fact that in Java you can not change the structure of an object. I read about the possibilities to change values of attribute fields. Can please someone explain to me what the author meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's meant that you cannot **add or remove methods or fields** of classes and you cannot **change the inheritance structure**, i.e. the superclass or implemented interfaces of classes.

Of course, you can change the value of fields, but that's not a structural change.

Comment: Okay I see. And is this a restriction coming from the JVM and Java's bytecode or because Java is statically typed?

Comment: I think this restriction is a consequence of statically typing and hence common for all those languages. Imagine the mess if you remove or change a method or even worse change the inheritance structure at runtime...